# how to change mysql slave database name in master slave replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, mysql-5.6

I am doing mysql master slave replication. I have mydb1 in master server and     mydb2 in slave server. I am doing it using mysql 5.6 and workbench 6.2. Now i want to replicate master server mydb1 to slave server mydb2.

I have also tried on slave server side but it doesn't work:

```
replicate-do-db = mydb2
replicate-rewrite-db= mydb1->mydb2
```

Am i missing something?
Your help would be nice.

Thank you.